# Multiply some members of an array by independenly drawn random numbers

Tags: julia

Suppose that I have a 1D array like so:

```
julia> myarray = ones(6)
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
 1.0
```

I make a mask that will select some elements, the first and second element in this example:

```
julia> mymask = [true; true; false; false; false; false;]
6-element Array{Bool,1}:
  true
  true
 false
 false
 false
 false
```

Now I want to multiply only the first and second elements by random numbers drawn from the same distribution, and save the result over the old array. But this will multiply them by the *same* value:

```
julia> myarray[mymask] = myarray[mymask] * rand(Normal(20,5))
julia> myarray
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 16.5642
 16.5642
  1.0
  1.0
  1.0
  1.0
```

My next thought was to try `myarray[mymask] = myarray[mymask] * rand(Normal(20,5),2)` but it gives an error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the cost of more lines, the following works:

```
function mularray!(myarray,mymask)
  maskpos = find(mymask)
  myrand = rand(Normal(20,5),length(maskpos))
  for i=1:length(maskpos)
    myarray[maskpos[i]] *= myrand[i]
  end
end
```

With the required operation done by

```
julia> mularray!(myarray,mymask)
julia> myarray
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 22.1761
 20.836 
  1.0   
  1.0   
  1.0   
  1.0
```

The advantage is in speed (benchmarked at more than 2x the shorter solution), perhaps readability (for some readers), but probably flexibility for other mutating operations.

Comment: Won't the speed advantage only be there until version 0.6 comes around? Then `.*` will be fusing.

Comment: This is indeed faster than the other solution, so I am selecting it. I am curious, though. Something like this for loop is probably what I would have eventually done left to my own devices. I would have thought that is not the fastest way to do it. Also, what does the "!" in the function definition mean?

Comment: the exclamation point is merely a [Julia style convention](http://docs.julialang.org/en/release-0.5/manual/style-guide/#append-to-names-of-functions-that-modify-their-arguments). it indicates that the function modifies one or more of its arguments.

Comment: It is very typical that this kind of loopy solution where you avoid unnecessary allocations is fast in Julia.

Comment: Another allocation can be removed by avoiding 'find' and using the 'sum' of 'mymask' instead of 'length'. Probably possible to squeeze a bit more performance

Answer (score 5):

You can make your multiplication explicitly elementwise:

```
julia> myarray[mymask] .*= rand(Normal(20,5), size(myarray[mymask]));

julia> myarray
6-element Array{Float64,1}:
 24.1747
 12.6375
  1.0   
  1.0   
  1.0   
  1.0
```

Comment: Thanks the pithiness of this way is very nice, I selected the other one as it is a bit faster on my machine.

Comment: @BenS. as a nod to the future, note that vectorized multiplication will probably be faster in Julia v0.6 than it currently is in v0.5. if and when you transition your code to v0.6, I suggest that you retry DSM's suggestion since your code speed could change.

Answer (score 0):

Because the value of the mask is bool, following method can be used

```
for i in eachindex(arr)
    mask[i] && (arr[i] *= rand(Normal(20,5)))
end
```

It is equivalent to

```
for i in eachindex(arr)
    if mask[i]
        arr[i] *= rand(Normal(20, 5))
    end
end
```

With this method, you can avoid allocation of `arr[mask]`